# Can't make work MyScript Angular example (myscript.com)

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, socket.io, interactive

I'm struggling to use MyScript inside an Angular 6 project.
I already cloned the following repo from GitHub:

https://github.com/MyScript/web-integration-samples/tree/master/angular-integration-examples

Installed all the dependencies with `npm install`.

Changed this line of code:

```
import * as MyScriptJS from 'myscript/src/myscript';
```

for:

```
import * as MyScriptJS from 'myscript/dist/myscript.min.js';
```

Because there wasn't any file called `myscript` inside `src` folder.

Finally I edited this piece of code that registers a new editor:

```
this.editor = MyScriptJS.register(this.domEditor.nativeElement, {
  recognitionParams: {
    type: 'MATH',
    protocol: 'WEBSOCKET',
    apiVersion: 'V4',
    server: {
      scheme: 'https',
      host: 'cloud.myscript.com',
      applicationKey: 'xxx',
      hmacKey: 'xxx',
    },
  },
});
```

And yes, I added both keys, took them from the Dashboard.

After this all I can see is a white canvas where I can draw but nothing happens, there is no other box to show any results.

This is a screen capture:

[image: Screen capture]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thanks for spotting the issue with our last version. This looks like the normal behavior as Math block does not have guidelines (the grey line displayed with text). Did you try to execute`$('#editor').editor.convert()` in the console ?